# getNextDataCell - Direction not defined

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to replicate the example for `getNextDataCell()` per the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getNextDataCell(Direction)) inside the Google Script Editor.

```
// Assume the active spreadsheet is blank.
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var range = sheet.getRange("C3:E5");
// Logs "C1"
Logger.log(range.getNextDataCell(Direction.UP).getA1Notation());
```

However, I get: `ReferenceError: Direction is not defined (line 8)`.

I don't understand why I should be defining `Direction`? Isn't that a built-in parameter?

Comment: I think that the official document is not correct. So in order to avoid the error, please modify `Direction.UP` to `SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP`. [Ref1](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/direction), [Ref2](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) But I'm not sure whether the result from the modified script is the value you want. I apologize for this. So I posted this as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

Change `Direction.UP` for `SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP`

Direction is part of the class SpreadsheetApp.

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)